# issues in Apple Metal API "setVertexBuffer:offset:atIndex:"

Tags: metal

I am new in Apple Metal, when running the apple sample code "[Creating and Sampling Textures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/creating_and_sampling_textures?language=objc)", I fond something strange, "*Figure 1*" is the result in my **Macmini 2018 (the GPU is Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630)**, you can see the quad's left bottom corner is squeezed, the origin source use `setVertexBuffer:offset:atIndex:` to set vertex buffer, I replace it to `setVertexBytes:length:atIndex:` and run, the result show as "*Figure 2*", it seems everything going fine, then I build and run the origin source in another machine(**Macbookpro, GPU is GeForce GT 750M**), the quad is render correct, result is show as "*Figure 2*", so does the source missing something or is there some issues in the function `setVertexBuffer:offset:atIndex:`?

Figure 1

[image: figure 1]

Figure 2

[image: Figure 2]

```
// Apple's origin source
//
static const AAPLVertex quadVertices[] =
    {
        // Pixel positions, Texture coordinates
        { {  250,  -250 },  { 1.f, 1.f } },
        { { -250,  -250 },  { 0.f, 1.f } },
        { { -250,   250 },  { 0.f, 0.f } },

        { {  250,  -250 },  { 1.f, 1.f } },
        { { -250,   250 },  { 0.f, 0.f } },
        { {  250,   250 },  { 1.f, 0.f } },
    };
...
...
...
//Create a vertex buffer, and initialize it with the quadVertices array
_vertices = [_device newBufferWithBytes:quadVertices
                                length:sizeof(quadVertices)
                               options:MTLResourceOptionCPUCacheModeDefault];
...
...
// set the vertex buffer
[renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:_vertices
                        offset:0
                      atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices];
```

I make the quadVertices as a global array, and replace the 
"setVertexBuffer:offset:atIndex:" to "setVertexBytes:length:atIndex:"

```
[renderEncoder setVertexBytes:&quadVertices
                       length:sizeof(quadVertices)
                       atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices];
```

Comment: I suspect it's a driver bug for the Intel GPU.

Comment: Amusingly, if you copy the vertices into the buffer every frame, it "works" (on my Intel HD Graphics 530). Something on the driver side appears to be corrupting only the 5th float in the buffer (setting it to the value 2^-134). If you're willing to waste the first 256 bytes of the buffer, offsetting the data to that position is a cheaper workaround than copying every frame. But this should definitely be reported via Feedback.

Comment: Is there an OSX update available for the problem device? Maybe it's a driver bug that is already fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I changed the MTLResourceOptions type to "MTLResourceCPUCacheModeWriteCombined" in the buffer create function, problem solved.

```
_vertices = [_device newBufferWithBytes:quadVertices
                                 length:sizeof(quadVertices)
             options:MTLResourceCPUCacheModeWriteCombined];
```

Now the sample works fine in both MacMini 2018(GPU is Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630) and Macbookpro(GPU is GeForce GT 750M).

Comment: Sounds more like a band-aid than a real solution. I'd still encourage you to [file Feedback](http://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Comment: feedback has been submited.